Trying to run a dropdown in angular but its not working

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { Dropdown, DropdownItem, DropdownModule } from 'primeng/dropdown';

interface City {
  name: string;
  code: string;
} 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule,DropdownModule],
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dropdown.component.css',
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit{
  cities: City[] | undefined;

  selectedCity: City | undefined;
  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
    this.cities = [
        { name: 'New York', code: 'NY' },
        { name: 'Rome', code: 'RM' },
        { name: 'London', code: 'LDN' },
        { name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST' },
        { name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS' }
    ];
  }

}

I am using this code in componet.ts file
 <p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" optionLabel="name" [showClear]="true"  [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }" placeholder="Select a City"></p-dropdown>

This is my component.html file. But my dropdown is not working.
In console i am getting this error
ERROR Error: NG05105: Unexpected synthetic listener @overlayContentAnimation.start found. Please make sure that:
  - Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.
  - There is corresponding configuration for the animation named `@overlayContentAnimation.start` defined in the `animations` field of the `@Component` decorator (see https://angular.io/api/core/Component#animations).

But after import
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule,DropdownModule,BrowserAnimationsModule],
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dropdown.component.css',
})

I am getting this error main.ts:5 ERROR Error: NG05100: Providers from the `BrowserModule` have already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor, import the `CommonModule` instead.

And after importing common module
ERROR Error: NG05105: Unexpected synthetic listener @overlayContentAnimation.start found. Please make sure that:
  - Either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule` are imported in your application.
  - There is corresponding configuration for the animation named `@overlayContentAnimation.start` defined in the `animations` field of the `@Component` decorator (see https://angular.io/api/core/Component#animations).

Same issue.
What i am missing in How to resolve this
